# Coloring a substring in a SpanLabel Codename one

Tags: codenameone

It seems `SpanLabel label = new SpanLabel("<html>Text color: <font color='red'>red</font></html>");` doesn't work in the `SpanLabel` of Codename One, and `label.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x0000ff);` is not my case, I want to get the same result of the first example, coloring a specific word. How to do it in Codename One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support that. This would mean parsing HTML for every widget which is something Swing can do because it has desktop processing power but doing this on a mobile phone would be painfully slow.

You have two option:

- Use `BrowserComponent` and HTML - this makes sense if you have a larger body of text but won't work well for many smaller entries
- Use something like [this](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-lightweight-rich-text-view.html)